# Randomly join two dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random, dataframe

I have two tables, one called Reasons that has 9 records and another containing IDs with 40k records.

IDs:

```
+------+------+
|pc_pid|pc_aid|
+------+------+
|  4569|  1101|
| 63961|  1101|
|140677|  4364|
|127113|     7|
| 96097|   480|
|  8309|  3129|
| 45218|    89|
|147036|  3289|
| 88493|  3669|
| 29973|  3129|
|127444|  3129|
| 36095|    89|
|131001|  1634|
|104731|   781|
| 79219|   244|
+-------------+
```

Reasons:

```
+-----------------+
|          reasons|
+-----------------+
|        follow up|
|         skin chk|
|      annual meet|
|review lab result|
|        REF BY DR|
|       sick visit|
|        body pain|
|             test|
|            other|
+-----------------+
```

I want output like this

```
|pc_pid|pc_aid| reason 
+------+------+-------------------
|  4569|  1101| body pain
| 63961|  1101| review lab result
|140677|  4364| body pain
|127113|     7| sick visit
| 96097|   480| test
|  8309|  3129| other
| 45218|    89| follow up
|147036|  3289| annual meet
| 88493|  3669| review lab result
| 29973|  3129| REF BY DR
|127444|  3129| skin chk
| 36095|    89|  other
```

In the reasons I have only 9 records and in the ID dataframe I have 40k records, I want to assign reason randomly to each and every id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution tries to be more robust to the number of reasons (ie. you can have as many reasons as you can reasonably fit in your cluster). If you just have few reasons (like the OP asks), you can probably broadcast them or embed them in a *udf* and easily solve this problem.

---

The general idea is to create an index (sequential) for the reasons and then random values from 0 to N (where N is the number of reasons) on the IDs dataset and then join the two tables using these two new columns. Here is how you can do this:

```
case class Reasons(s: String)
defined class Reasons

case class Data(id: Long)
defined class Data
```

Data will hold the IDs (simplified version of the OP) and Reasons will hold some simplified reasons.

```
val d1 = spark.createDataFrame( Data(1) :: Data(2) :: Data(10) :: Nil)
d1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint]

d1.show()

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
| 10|
+---+

val d2 = spark.createDataFrame( Reasons("a") :: Reasons("b") :: Reasons("c") :: Nil)

+---+
|  s|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
|  c|
+---+
```

We will later need the number of reasons so we calculate that first.

```
val numerOfReasons = d2.count()

val d2Indexed = spark.createDataFrame(d2.rdd.map(_.getString(0)).zipWithIndex)

d2Indexed.show()
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  a|  0|
|  b|  1|
|  c|  2|
+---+---+

val d1WithRand = d1.select($"id", (rand * numerOfReasons).cast("int").as("rnd"))
```

The last step is to join on the new columns and the remove them.

```
val res = d1WithRand.join(d2Indexed, d1WithRand("rnd") === d2Indexed("_2")).drop("_2").drop("rnd")

res.show()

+---+---+
| id| _1|
+---+---+
|  2|  a|
| 10|  b|
|  1|  c|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

pyspark random join itself

```py
data_neg = data_pos.sortBy(lambda x: uniform(1, 10000))
data_neg = data_neg.coalesce(1, False).zip(data_pos.coalesce(1, True))
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to randomly join dataA (huge dataframe) and dataB (smaller dataframe, sorted by any column):

```
dfB = dataB.withColumn(
    "index", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("col")) - 1
)
dfA = dataA.withColumn("index", (F.rand() * dfB.count()).cast("bigint"))
df = dfA.join(dfB, on="index", how="left").drop("index")
```

Since dataB is already sorted, row numbers can be assigned over sorted window with high degree of parallelism. F.rand() is another highly parallel function, so adding index to dataA will be very fast as well.

If dataB is small enough, you may benefit from broadcasting it.

This method is better than using:

- zipWithIndex: Can be very expensive to convert dataframe to rdd, zipWithIndex, and then to df.
- monotonically_increasing_id: Need to be used with row_number which will collect all the partitions into a single executor.

Reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-sequential-ids-to-a-spark-dataframe-fa0df5566ff6